# Laravel update all related models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have:

```
    $enquiry = Enquiry::find($id);
    $enquiry->load('parts', 'buyingParts', 'fees', 'buyingFees');
    $duplicate = $enquiry->replicate();

    $next_number_e = Enquiry::where('display_code', $duplicate->display_code)->max('display_number') + 1;

    $duplicate->display_number = $next_number_e;

    $duplicate->push();
    $duplicate->parts()->update(['enquiryId' => $duplicate->id]);
    $duplicate->parts->save();
```

But this doesn't work.

How do I get it to update all the attribute `enquiryId` for all parts associated with duplicate?

Comment: You can try with Query builder, something like `DB::table('parts')
            ->where('your_field_key', $your_key)
            ->update(['enquiryId' => $duplicate->id]);`

Comment: @Nerea The problem is, is that this would update all the parts in both the duplicate and the original, which is not what I want. It needs to happen before $duplicate is pushed/saved.